# REGEX Match number in a line with a keyword

Tags: python, regex

I tried many patterns, but cannot get the correct result. I want to match only float when the line has keyword `range` at the beginning. My trouble is that the `range` can follow by a `:`, `:` , `:`,  `:`,   `:` , etc.

My best try is to use two patterns:

#1. `(?i)(?<=range[: ])[:a-zA-Z0-9.$ -]+`

#2. `[0-9.]+`

First run regex with the pattern #1, then get the ouput of pattern #1 and run regex one more time with pattern #2

How can I do that in one single pattern? Thanks so much

One more thing: my code is Python

Input:
`range: $0.82`
--> Expected output: `0.82`

Input:
`range:0.82`
--> Expected output: `0.82`

Input:
`range:  0.82 - 0.85`
--> Expected output: `0.82`, `0.85`

Input:
`range : 0.82 - 0.85`
--> Expected output: `0.82`, `0.85`

Input:
`range   :  0.82 - 0.85`
--> Expected output: `0.82`, `0.85`

Input:
`range 0.82   0.85`
--> Expected output: `0.82`, `0.85`

Comment: Your attempt seems pretty far off. Why do you use `(?i)` if you explicitly enumerate both uppercase and lowercase alphabetics anyway? And why do you want to permit alphabetics if your range should consist of numbers? Did you search before asking?

Comment: Can you use `regex` module in python instead or `re` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can make use of the Python[regex PyPi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) Then you can get multiple occurrences:

```
(?<=^range\b[\s:$-\d.]*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert that to the left is

  - `^range\b` Match `range` at the start of the string
  - `[\s:$-\d.]*` Optionally match all allowed chars that could be in between
- `)` Close the lookbehind assertion
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jPfJHJ/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##dY/BCsIwEETP7lcsoYdE2yCKIMHSD2kqVJrWQE1DkoN@fWxrFQQ9zc5jd5mxj3AdzD5GfbODC@hUp@4APjhtOo85lkBcbTolMNny446kb//tECeP2SSHD0bxGyP@O5ghviBUYOsQlDNjDkdoccrP85a8lNKLJJMNr9ZMNhtaCMlHZQUBaAeHHrXBpYSAlR2HgHQux1ttmrrv6fI7Rc9YjE8)

Example

```
import regex

strings = [
"range: $0.82",
"range:0.82",
"range:  0.82 - 0.85",
"range : 0.82 - 0.85",
"range   :  0.82 - 0.85",
"range 0.82   0.85"
]
pattern = r"(?<=^range\b[\s:$-\d.]*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?"

for s in strings:
    print (regex.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['0.82']
['0.82']
['0.82', '0.85']
['0.82', '0.85']
['0.82', '0.85']
['0.82', '0.85']
```

Comment: yes, `regex` module is right approach

Comment: Very nice and descriptive answer. Could you please do let me know what's the main difference between re and regex module? Also in this specific situation why we have choosen to use this one, will be grateful to you, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The main difference here is that the regex module supports an [infinite width](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#width) lookbehind assertion, which is handy if you don't know the amount of matches that there can be up front.

Comment: Of course you can also use the `re` module. If you know that there are 1 or 2 occurrences that you want, you can make the second capture group optional as Nick has done nicely in his answer. If there can be more occurrences, then you can for example first match all occurrences including the leading keyword as a single match, and then use split or use another pattern that matches the separate ones.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid regex completely. Those lines are not difficult to parse.

```
def parse(line):
    if not line.startswith('range'):
        return
    line = line.replace(':',' ').replace('$','')
    for token in line.split():
        try:
            yield float(token)
        except ValueError:
            continue
            

input_data = ['range: $0.82',
              'range:0.82',
              'range:  0.82 - 0.85',
              'range : 0.82 - 0.85',
              'range   :  0.82 - 0.85',
              'range 0.82   0.85']

r = [list(i) for i in map(parse, input_data)]
print(r)
[[0.82], [0.82], [0.82, 0.85], [0.82, 0.85], [0.82, 0.85], [0.82, 0.85]]
```

Comment: Very interesting. I thought that regex is the most simple solution for this case. But you make me wrong. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me - however - there are probably a number of more efficient ways of doing it:

```py
import re

input_data = ['range: $0.82',
              'range:0.82',
              'range:  0.82 - 0.85',
              'range : 0.82 - 0.85',
              'range   :  0.82 - 0.85',
              'range 0.82   0.85']

for i in range(len(input_data)):
    output = re.findall(r'(range)(\s*:?\s*[$]*)([0-9]*.[0-9]*)(\s*-?\s*)([0-9]*.[0-9]*)?', input_data[i])
    a = list(output[0])[2]
    b = list(output[0])[4]
    print(f'Input: {input_data[i]} --> Expected output: {a} , {b}')
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Input: range: $0.82 --> Expected output: 0.82 , 
Input: range:0.82 --> Expected output: 0.82 , 
Input: range:  0.82 - 0.85 --> Expected output: 0.82 , 0.85
Input: range : 0.82 - 0.85 --> Expected output: 0.82 , 0.85
Input: range   :  0.82 - 0.85 --> Expected output: 0.82 , 0.85
Input: range 0.82   0.85 --> Expected output: 0.82 , 0.85
```

You could also add some IF-statements to check to see if 'b' is empty, and control the output as required. However, I think the main thing that you wanted to achieve was a single REGEX statement that could extract the two numbers in question (if available).

**Regex statement explanation**:

```
r'(range)(\s*:?\s*[$]*)([0-9]*.[0-9]*)(\s*-?\s*)([0-9]*.[0-9]*)?'
```

**First Group:** `(range)`

This puts '**range**' into the first group.

**Second Group:** `(\s*:?\s*[$]*)`

- `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters
- `:?` matches an optional colon (:)
- `[$]*` matches zero or more dollar signs ($)

**Third Group:** `([0-9]*.[0-9]*)`

- `[0-9]*` matches zero or more numbers
- `.` matches a decimal point
- this is the group that relates to the number (**0.82**)

**Fourth Group:** `(\s*-?\s*)`

- `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters
- `-?` matches an optional hyphen

**Fifth Group:** `([0-9]*.[0-9]*)?`

- `[0-9]*` matches zero or more numbers
- `.` matches a decimal point
- The `?` at the end suggests that the group is optional.
- This is the group that holds the second number (**0.85**)

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regex to extract your data:

```
^\s*range\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?
```

Regex explanation:

- `^` : beginning of string
- `\s*range` : asserts the string starts with `range` (possibly preceded by whitespace, if you don't want that remove the `\s*`
- `\D*` : some number of non-digit characters
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` : a number, captured in group 1
- `(?:\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?` an optional group of some non-digits followed by a number, captured in group 2

In python

```py
import re

input_data = ['range: $0.82',
              'range:0.82',
              'range:  0.82 - 0.85',
              'range : 0.82 - 0.85',
              'range   :  0.82 - 0.85',
              'range 0.82   0.85']
results = [re.findall(r'^\s*range\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?', d)[0] for d in input_data]
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[
 ('0.82', ''),
 ('0.82', ''),
 ('0.82', '0.85'),
 ('0.82', '0.85'),
 ('0.82', '0.85'),
 ('0.82', '0.85')
]
```

Comment: @Thefourthbird yeah, I guess I did overcomplicate... :) I've corrected, thanks.